# Marathon - How to resolve a hanging deployment

Tags: mesos, marathon

I have an application that was running smoothly. I pushed a newly updated Docker image and restarted the app through Marathon's UI. The redeployment is now frozen, stuck on `Progress 1/2`.

First, what does `Progress` indicate and why is it `1/2`? When I restart other applications on Marathon, they all have a progress ratio of `1/1`.

Second, how can I debug this? When I run the container locally, I don't have any issues.

Comment: Take a look at logs. Probably you are running out of resources or deployments keep failing due to health check.

Comment: Logs for Marathon or Mesos? Do you know where they typically are?

Comment: Mesos logs usually are in /var/log/mesos Marathon could be appended to /var/log/syslog

Comment: I am also facing same issue .If you resolved can you please share .

Comment: check mesos sandbox logs for any errors

Comment: I have the same issue. Sometimes it happen due to missing resources to run the application, sometimes it just bug for example sometime when I revert a deployment, it does the revert but the deployment is still hanging. Very annoying